# how to set a zoom level using Gmap4rails?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, google-maps, gmaps4rails

I've just setup a new project following this video http://youtu.be/R0l-7en3dUw.
I was wondering how can I set the map zoom level in a project like this.
I've looked at the src on github and since in `map.coffee` there isn't something like `zoomTo: (zoomLvl)->  @getServiceObject().setZoom(zoomLvl)` I don't have any idea how to do it. So can anyone help me?

I've tried this kind of solution as suggested here ([zoom in to particular region in gmap4rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12974802/zoom-in-to-particular-region-in-gmap4rails)) but with any good result:

```
Gmaps.map.callback = function() {
   google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(Gmaps.map.getMapObject(), 'idle', function(){
     var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(new google.maps.LatLng(10, 0), new google.maps.LatLng(0, 10));
     Gmaps.map.serviceObject.panToBounds(bounds);
   }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first you're mixing methods from v1 and v2. v2 arrived in october 2013, all previous answers wont be helpful.

`Gmaps.map.callback` is from v1.

in v2, you can do:

```
#work directly with the google object:
handler.getMap().setZoom(zoom_level)
```

Comment: thank you! I was trying desperately to make it work and I did not realize I used methods of different versions. Thanks again!

Comment: my pleasure, just look at the date of the answers next time!