# gmaps4rails v2 polygon click event

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps, ruby-on-rails-4, gmaps4rails, gmaps4rails2

What I am trying to do is something similar to this ([how to set a zoom level using Gmap4rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19954579/how-to-set-a-zoom-level-using-gmap4rails/19955229#19955229))
but instead of:

```
google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(Gmaps.map.getMapObject(), 'idle', function(){}
```

I want something like

```
google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(polygon, 'click', function(){}
```

_
So I tried to do this as an experiment:

```
handler.buildMap({ provider: {}, internal: {id: 'map'}}, function(){
      polygon = handler.addPolygons(<%= raw @myhash.to_json %>);
}
google.maps.event.addListener(polygon, "click", function( evt ) {
      alert("hello!");
});
```

But it doesn't work....

So my question is, how would I add a listener for Polygons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a matter of variable scope and the real google object lives within the gmaps4rails proxy object:

```
handler.buildMap({ provider: {}, internal: {id: 'map'}}, function(){
  var polygons = handler.addPolygons(<%= raw @myhash.to_json %>);

  for (var i=0;i < polygons.length; i++){
    var polygon = polygons[i];
    google.maps.event.addListener(polygon.getServiceObject(), "click", function(evt) {
      alert("hello!");
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The docs say `google.maps.event.addListener` and `google.maps.event.addListenerOnce` only accept a single object as their first argument, so the array of `markers` probably won't work. You'll need to call `addListener` once for each Marker. Something roughly like:

```
handler.buildMap({ provider: {}, internal: {id: 'map'}}, function(){
    markers = handler.addMarkers(<%= raw @myhash.to_json %>);

    for (marker in markers) {
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function( evt ) {
            alert("hello!");
        });
    }
}
```

should work alright.

Comment: I actually want to have a listener for my polygon, sorry for the confusion. I will edit my question....

Comment: i edited the question and i hope it is more clear now, if you know the answer or have an idea, please let me know. Thanks